# Iterate Site Collection Administrators across web app

Tags: permissions, site-collection

How can I find out all the sites where the user is a primary site collection administrator or a secondary site collection administrator.

We have around 200+ site collections and growing and hence looking to avoid a loop. For membership we are currently using "contentclass:sts_site" with SearchServiceApplicationProxy.

I guess I should have added more details to the above - Since I already have the code for the Search Application Proxy utilizing the object model, preferably I was looking towards a solution where I could still utilize Search Application Proxy to fetch all details in one go.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you you want

```
$user = "domian\username"
Get-SPSite | Where {$_.Owner.UserLogin -eq $user -or $_.SecondaryContact.UserLogin -eq $user}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was getting at, except my PoSH sucks :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a box handy to give you exact code, but you could use powershell to get all SPSites within a web application, and filter by a given username (`Owner` is the property you want from each `SPSite` object).

Comment: The owner is a single user value right? And the owner is automatically assumed to be a site collection administrator. If I'm not mistaken, you can load up more site collection administrators, who won't show up as owners.

Comment: Yes, the 'owner' is the Primary Site Collection administrator, and there is only one, and this is assigned (normally) via Central Administration.

Comment: Ah, i see he's asking for the Primary and Secondary, Owners will work then. ;)